# XML into json coming with backslash using javax.ws.rs

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot, jersey

I need an API to generate a dynamic XML. The output is fine in Console but in API result added a backslash before double quote in XML attribute.

```
@GET
@Path("xml")
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
@Produces({  MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
public StringBuffer GetXMl(){

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("<tv name=\"sony\"></tv>");
    System.out.println(sb); 
    // Here O/P is <tv name="sony"></tv> and it is fine
    return sb;
}
```

But API is producing as below.

```
   <tv name=\"sony\"></tv>
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. I am getting an error about MessageBodyWriter not found. Is this real code that you have tested to get the result? If not, please post real code that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check produce type should be @Produces({  MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })

convert StringBuffer  into String...

Now working fine for me.

```
@GET
@Path("xml")
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
@Produces({  MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
public String GetXMl(){
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("<tv name=\"sony\"></tv>");
    String xml =sb.toString();
    return xml;
}
```